# Automating the height of a drop cap initial

Tags: macros, drop-cap

How can I modify the following macro to automatically have the initial with the height indicated in the picture?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newlength\CLett% Nuova dimensione

 \newcommand*\capolettera[2]{% #1 lettera da ingrandire #2 testo in maiuscoletto
\par\noindent\setbox\z@\hbox{%
             \scalebox{1.35}{%
                            \huge#1}%
                            }%
\CLett=\wd\z@\hangindent\CLett\hangafter-2\relax%
\raisebox{-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\llap{\box\z@\kern1pt}}\textsc{#2}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\capolettera{L}{orem ipsum} at nusquam appellantur his, ut eos erant homero
concludaturque. Albucius appellantur deterruisset id eam, vivendum
partiendo dissentiet ei ius. Vis melius facilisis ea, sea id convenire
referrentur, takimata adolescens ex duo. Ei harum argumentum per. Eam
vidit exerci appetere ad, ut vel zzril intellegam interpretaris.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "have an initial"?

Comment: @PeterGrill I have updated my question

Comment: it should be `\dimexpr\baselineskip+1ex\relax` but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @FormlessCloud Don't change answered questions to add new requests; rather ask a followup question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

I used `\resizebox` rather than `\scalebox` to force the initial to `\baselineskip` + the height of the small caps text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newlength\CLett% Nuova dimensione

 \newcommand*\capolettera[2]{% #1 lettera da ingrandire #2 testo in maiuscoletto
\par\noindent
 \setbox8\hbox{\textsc{#2}}%
 \setbox\z@\hbox{%
             \resizebox{!}{\dimexpr\baselineskip+\ht8\relax}{%
                            \huge#1}%
                            }%
\CLett=\wd\z@\hangindent\CLett\hangafter-2\relax%
\raisebox{-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\llap{\box\z@\kern1pt}}{\box8}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\capolettera{L}{orem ipsum} at nusquam appellantur his, ut eos erant homero
concludaturque. Albucius appellantur deterruisset id eam, vivendum
partiendo dissentiet ei ius. Vis melius facilisis ea, sea id convenire
referrentur, takimata adolescens ex duo. Ei harum argumentum per. Eam
vidit exerci appetere ad, ut vel zzril intellegam interpretaris.

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks ! I get an `OverFull \hbox` at the line 23 is it normal?

Comment: did you get one before in the original mwe? (I'll check)

Comment: yes the original MWE was the same, it's just an artifact of typesetting latin with english hyphenation patterns. So it can't set the paragraph text, not related to the drop cap.

Comment: in fact if I use `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` I haven't it anymore. Thanks again ;) !

Comment: I have forgotten one thing: the initial is only stretched to fit the `\baselineskip` + the height of the small caps text or it is rescaled to have the right proportions?

Comment: not sure if I understand the question but height and width are scaled by the same factor (that's what the `!` means in the width argument of `\resizebox`)

Comment: I don't would that the initial is only stretched, but I would that it is resized to fit the height of `\baselineskip` + the height of the small caps text, and have the correct proportions. If the height and width are scaled by the same factor is ok.

Comment: I've added a new detail to my question, I would like to control also the space between the drop cap initial and the lines of text at its right.

Comment: @FormlessCloud as egreg commented it's best not to alter old questions in that way but anyway changing `\huge#1}%`  to `\huge#1}\kern1in`% would add some space I would assume

Answer (score 3):

I like this a lot. I made a couple of small changes: 1) I introduced an optional argument to tell the macro how many lines to drop the cap (2 being the default); 2) I used `\unhbox8` so that the spacing between the words in small caps is consistent with the rest of the line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength\CLett% Nuova dimensione

 \newcommand*\capolettera[3][2]{% #1 lettera da ingrandire #2 testo in maiuscoletto
    \par
    \noindent
    \setbox8\hbox{\textsc{#3}}%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{%
        \resizebox{!}{\dimexpr#1\baselineskip-\baselineskip+\ht8\relax}{\huge#2}%
    }%
    \CLett=\wd\z@%
    \hangindent\CLett
    \hangafter-#1\relax
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-#1\baselineskip+\baselineskip\relax}[0pt][0pt]%
        {\llap{\box\z@\kern1pt}}{\unhbox8}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\capolettera[4]{L}{orem ipsum} at nusquam appellantur his, ut eos erant homero
concludaturque. Albucius appellantur deterruisset id eam, vivendum
partiendo dissentiet ei ius. Vis melius facilisis ea, sea id convenire
referrentur, takimata adolescens ex duo. Ei harum argumentum per. Eam
vidit exerci appetere ad, ut vel zzril intellegam interpretaris.

\end{document}
```

[image: 4-line drop cap.]

One of the reasons this is so nice is that you can do things like this:

`\capolettera[4]{\textbf{L}}{\kern-6pt orem ipsum}`

[image]